# How we can sort and group data from the Spark RDDs?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, scala-collections, rdd

The data that is in data.csv file is:

```
07:36:00 PM 172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:33:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
07:34:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
07:35:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:44:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
07:45:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:46:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
07:47:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:48:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:36:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:37:00 PM 172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:37:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
07:38:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
07:39:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:50:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
07:51:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:52:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
07:53:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:54:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:40:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
```

This my Code:

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

 object ScalaApp {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "Program")

     // we take the raw data in CSV format and convert it into a

  val data = sc.textFile("data.csv")
 .map(line => line.split(","))

 .map(GroupRecord => (GroupRecord(0),
GroupRecord(1),GroupRecord(2),GroupRecord(3),GroupRecord(4),GroupRecord(5)))

val numPurchases = data.count()
val d1=data.groupByKey(GroupRecord(2)) // here is the error

println("No: " + numPurchases)
println("Grouped Data" + d1)

}
}
```

I just want the same data that is group by source-IP (2nd column) and order by time (1st column ).
So my require data is :

```
  07:33:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
  07:34:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
  07:35:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:37:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
  07:38:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
  07:39:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:40:00 PM   172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:44:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
  07:45:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:46:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
  07:47:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:50:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
  07:51:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:52:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
  07:53:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:54:00 PM   172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:36:00 PM   172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
  07:37:00 PM   172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
```

but i have problem with my code so plz help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Glennie pointed out, you don't create a key-value pair for the `groupByKey` operation. However, you can also use `groupBy(_._3)` to obtain the same result. In order to sort each group with respect to the first column, you can apply a `flatMapValues` after the grouping to sort the items in each group. The following code does exactly that:

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val data = sc.textFile("data.csv")
      .map(line => line.split("\\s+"))
      .map(GroupRecord => (GroupRecord(2), (GroupRecord(0), GroupRecord(1),GroupRecord(2),GroupRecord(3),GroupRecord(4),GroupRecord(5))))

    // sort the groups by the first tuple field
    val result = data.groupByKey.flatMapValues(x => x.toList.sortBy(_._1))

    // assign the partition ID to each item to see that each group is sorted
    val resultWithPartitionID = result.mapPartitionsWithIndex((id, it) => it.map(x => (id, x)))

    // print the contents of the RDD, elements of different partitions might be interleaved
    resultWithPartitionID foreach println

    val collectedResult = resultWithPartitionID.collect.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)

    // print collected results
    println(collectedResult.mkString("\n"))
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your second `map` creates a `Tuple6` instead of a key-value pair, which is what is required if you want to do a xxxByKey operation. If you want to group by the 2nd column, you should make `GroupRecord(1)` your key and the rest values, and then call `groupByKey`, like this:

```
data
  .map(GroupRecord => (GroupRecord(1),(GroupRecord(0),GroupRecord(2),GroupRecord(3),GroupRecord(4),GroupRecord(5)))
  .groupByKey()
```

Comment: still giving error   : 



                     _italic_ ** val data = sc.textFile("data.csv").map(line => line.split(","))

                       .map(GroupRecord => (GroupRecord(1),            (GroupRecord(0),GroupRecord(2),GroupRecord(3),GroupRecord(4),GroupRecord(5))).groupByKey()



                println("Grouped Data" + data) **

Comment: You cannot print an RDD like that. Try  `data foreach println` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The above mentioned solution will work fine . But When data increases to large size i am not sure as u need to handle reshuffling

Best way is create a dataframe and using sqlContext order BY IP address and Time

Answer (score 0):

Here we are require to convert it to key, value pairs to apply GroupByKey mechanism and after that the values will get convert to Iterable set and to apply sorting to the values of every key we need to convert it to sequence and then apply sortby functionality and after that flatMap function will flatten the sequential values to String sets.

Data.csv ->

```
07:36:00 PM 172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:33:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
07:34:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
07:35:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:44:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
07:45:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:46:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
07:47:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:48:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:36:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:37:00 PM 172.20.16.107   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:37:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.66
07:38:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.47
07:39:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:50:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.49
07:51:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:52:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.33
07:53:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:54:00 PM 172.20.16.106   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
07:40:00 PM 172.20.16.105   104.70.250.141  80  57188   0.48
```

Code ->

```
val data = sc.textFile("src/Data.csv")
  .map(line => {
    val GroupRecord = line.split("\t")

    ((GroupRecord(1)), (GroupRecord(0), GroupRecord(2), GroupRecord(3), GroupRecord(4), GroupRecord(5)))
  })

val numPurchases = data.count()

val d1 = data.groupByKey().map(f => (f._1, f._2.toSeq.sortBy(f => f._1))).flatMapValues(f => f).map(f => (f._2._1, f._1, f._2._2, f._2._3, f._2._4, f._2._5))

d1 foreach (println(_))

println("No: " + numPurchases)
```

Comment: Error:
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Sep 30, 2015 10:44:20 AM